How to save a txt file in Android
I am trying to create an application to scan two barcodes and then save the informations in a accessible text file on my phone. Can someone help?
MainActivity.java :

package com.example.barcodescanjava;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ScanContract;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ScanOptions;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn_scan1;
    Button btn_scan2;
    Button btn_store;

    TextView barcode1;
    TextView barcode2;

    int i = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_store = findViewById(R.id.btn_store);
        btn_scan1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_scan1);
        btn_scan2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_scan2);

        barcode1 = findViewById(R.id.barcode1);
        barcode2 = findViewById(R.id.barcode2);

        btn_scan1.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            i = 0;
            scanCode();
        });

        btn_scan2.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            i = 1;
            scanCode();
        });

        btn_store.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder2.setTitle("Occhio");

            String textToSave = barcode1.getText().toString();
            String textToSave2 = barcode2.getText().toString();

            if(!textToSave.equals("Sorgente") && !textToSave2.equals("Destinazione")) {

                String filename = "Inventario.txt";
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs(); // Crea la directory se non esiste
                }
                File file = new File(dir, filename);

                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    fos.write((textToSave + " " + textToSave2).getBytes());
                    builder2.setMessage("SALVATO");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    builder2.setMessage("Errore durante il salvataggio del file");
                }

                builder2.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();

                barcode1.setText("Sorgente");
                barcode2.setText("Destinazione");
            } else {
                builder2.setMessage("Devi scansionare entrambi i codici");
                builder2.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });btn_store.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder2.setTitle("Occhio");

            String textToSave = barcode1.getText().toString();
            String textToSave2 = barcode2.getText().toString();

            if(!textToSave.equals("Sorgente") && !textToSave2.equals("Destinazione")) {

                String filename = "Inventario.txt";
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs(); // Crea la directory se non esiste
                }
                File file = new File(dir, filename);

                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    fos.write((textToSave + " " + textToSave2).getBytes());
                    builder2.setMessage("SALVATO");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    builder2.setMessage("Errore durante il salvataggio del file");
                }

                builder2.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();

                barcode1.setText("Sorgente");
                barcode2.setText("Destinazione");
            } else {
                builder2.setMessage("Devi scansionare entrambi i codici");
                builder2.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void scanCode() {
        ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions();
        options.setPrompt("Volume su per la torcia");
        options.setBeepEnabled(true);
        options.setOrientationLocked(true);
        options.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
        barLauncher.launch(options);
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> barLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(), result -> {
        if (result.getContents() != null) {
            if(i==0){
                barcode1.setText(result.getContents());
            }
            else{
                barcode2.setText(result.getContents());
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Result");
            builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });
}


AndroidManifest.xml : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BarcodeScanjava"
        android:installLocation="preferExternal"
        tools:targetApi="34">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CaptureAct"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@style/zxing_CaptureTheme"
            tools:ignore="DiscouragedApi" />

    </application>
</manifest>

activity_main.xml : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_scan1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:text="Scansiona Sorgente" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_scan2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:text="Scansiona Destinazione" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_store"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
        android:text="Salva" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barcode1"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="Sorgente" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barcode2"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Destinazione" />
</RelativeLayout>

I tried with different methods, but none of them worked.
I expect the file to be saved in the documents folder and then be accessible and readable by the user.

I can suggest a few fixes for your code:
First of all, don't forget fos.close(); after fos.write((textToSave + " " + textToSave2).getBytes());
Secondly, you invoke btn_store.setOnClickListener twice in a row, which is unnecessary.
Also, for SDK version 32 and below you need to explicitly ask the user for permissions and for newer versions you need to use MediaStore.
You can ask for permissions where do you want, for example, in onCreate function:
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        askForPermissions();
    }
    [...]

Giving this all together, I can suggest a new btn_store onClickListener:
btn_store.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder2.setTitle("Occhio");

        String textToSave = barcode1.getText().toString();
        String textToSave2 = barcode2.getText().toString();

        if(!textToSave.equals("Sorgente") && !textToSave2.equals("Destinazione")) {
            String filename = "Inventario.txt";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                boolean isSaved = saveTextToFileWithMediaStore(filename, textToSave + " " + textToSave2);
                if (isSaved) {
                    builder2.setMessage("SALVATO");
                } else {
                    builder2.setMessage("Errore durante il salvataggio del file");
                }
            } else {
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs(); // Crea la directory se non esiste
                }
                File file = new File(dir, filename);

                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    fos.write((textToSave + " " + textToSave2).getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                    builder2.setMessage("SALVATO");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    builder2.setMessage("Errore durante il salvataggio del file");
                }

                barcode1.setText("Sorgente");
                barcode2.setText("Destinazione");
            }

            builder2.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
        } else {
            builder2.setMessage("Devi scansionare entrambi i codici");
            builder2.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();
        }
    });

where the required functions are:
private boolean saveTextToFileWithMediaStore(String fileName, String text) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents/");

    Uri externalContentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    Uri fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(externalContentUri, values);

    try {
        if (fileUri != null) {
            OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.write(text.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

private void askForPermissions() {
    int permissionsStatus = ContextCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permissionsStatus != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                1234
        );
    }
}

UPD:
To use the same file instead of creating new one each time, please use modified function:
private boolean saveTextToFileWithMediaStore(String fileName, String text) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents/");

    Uri externalContentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
    
    // Check if the file already exists
    Uri existingFileUri = getFileUri(externalContentUri, fileName);
    
    if (existingFileUri != null) {
        // "wa" mode for appending text
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(existingFileUri, "wa");
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.write((" " + text).getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
            }
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        try {
            Uri fileUri = getContentResolver().insert(externalContentUri, values);
            if (fileUri != null) {
                OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(fileUri);
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.write(text.getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private Uri getFileUri(Uri externalContentUri, String fileName) {
    String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{ fileName };
    Uri existingFileUri = null;

    try (Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(externalContentUri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            existingFileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    externalContentUri,
                    cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID))
            );
        }
    }

    return existingFileUri;
}

(Do not forget to modify your code for older SDK versions the same way if required).

thank u man, the code seems working so far, just a problem, everytime I press the store button, a new "Inventario.txt" is created, is there a method to just write all the information in the same file?

@PaoloMorello I have added modified function to fix this issue, I hope it will help you.
If you found my post useful please mark it as an answer, thank you :)

tysm man u saved me
